# rotate 3D displacement vector in a 3D stack

Tags: 3d, rotation, volume

In a 3D stack, I have several voxels as showed in the image below.

[rotation of the displacement vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW67h.png)

I compute the displacement vectors for each pair of voxels. The displacement vector between two voxel A and B would be C=B-A. My aim is to add 90° to each displacement vector.  For this, I'm trying to use the Rodrigues' rotation formula:

```
r′=cosΦr+sinΦl×r+(1−cosΦ)(r.l)l
```

where r is the vector we want to rotate, Φ is the angle of rotation and L is the rotation axis with the director vector l.

My question is : in my case presented in the image, how would I choose the rotation axis ? the rotation would be one the x or y or z axis ? How can I do this ?

Thank you

Comment: The choice is yours, and depends on the situation. Without any more information the only constraint is to take a direction with a non-zero perpendicular component to any motion.

Comment: Indeed, my aim is to compute fastly and simply the normal vectors on each voxel. What I proposed seems  to give oriented normal deduced from the rotated vectors of each voxel. but I don't really understand your solution. How could I estimate the the non zero perpendicular component ? (do product ?)

Comment: What I mean is, there are an *infinite* number of possible rotation axes, the only invalid case being when the axis is (anti-)parallel to the vector you want to rotate. Without further information about your objective / context it would be impossible to decide on a well-defined procedure to determine the axis.

Comment: the context of my problem is related to the computation of the curvature of each voxel. For this, I begin by computing the normal vector of each voxel, then, I compute the curvature of each voxel using the difference of normal vectors and 3D coordinates: curvature(voxel_i)=(N_i - N_i-1)dot(p_i - p_i-1)/||p_i - p_i-1||^2, where N_i is the normal vector of the voxel i and p_i is the 3D coordinates.

Comment: In that case, unless I'm still misunderstanding something, just take the cross-product of the displacement vector with the normal.

Comment: This is the problem, I do not have the normal ! the normal will be the rotated  displacement vector

Comment: By normal I meant the common rotation axis for all of your displacement vectors (in the case of the diagram it might e.g. point out of the page). If you don't have a *well-defined procedure* to find this then you cannot really progress

Comment: Yes, I agree, the normal will be the axis pointing out of the page. I'm thinking about computing the dot product between a displacement vector and each axis (x,y,z) and pick up the one having the dot product near to 0...

Comment: I would recommend against this method, since it might result in different rotation axis for each displacement vector.